# How does 舟 resemble a boat?

Tags: glyph-origin

I don't wholly fathom [this progression chart](https://www.decodemandarinchinese.com/component-%E8%88%9F-boat/).

[image]

1. I ticked, in green below, the only glyph that resembles anything like a boat, but that "Bronze Script" doesn't resemble 舟.
2. Doubtless, boats are "horizontal". Their length > their width. All the other glyphs are vertical, so I can't imagine how they resemble a boat.
3. Boats ought be sealed lest water enters. But my red arrow indicate openings and gaps where water can enter and sink the boat.
4. What does the curvy tail, indicated by my purple arrows, signify? The rudder?

I screenshot [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%88%9F)

[image]

and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%9F#Chinese).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple poster clearly depicting the correlation between what a boat would have looked like during the period when the character 舟 was first penned:

> [image]

Now of course as it is a pictographic character the orientation can easily be changed depending on the person writing it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please cite or link to the poster?

Comment: @AYX.CLDR Here's a link: http://www.chinesetimeschool.com/Portals/2/cms/images/201404/Learn-Chinese-Word-Formation-zhou-Boat-0.jpeg I'm not sure of its true origin though.